# How do I determine the physical file server for a DFS path?

Tags: microsoft-distributed-file-system

Given a DFS path, how can I programatically determine which physical file server it maps to?

Comment: It would help to know what language you're programming in, may want to add that tag to the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NetDfsGetInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524812%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: the above link is 404.
here is a working one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmdfs/nf-lmdfs-netdfsgetinfo

Answer (score 1):

Powershell:

Get-DfsnFolderTarget -Path "\dfsnamespace\dfsshare"